# How to check whether script input param is among list of acceptable values?

Tags: python

I have a simple case here, but it made me realize I don't have a good strategy for handling more interesting input.  How can I check (ideally in O(1) time), that the input is among a list of whitelisted values?

```
import time

global wait_time_secs

def validateUsage(arg_list):
  """Validates that the user called this program correctly and teaches the
     expected usage otherwise"""
  global wait_time_secs    
  # Discard the first argument which is always the script name
  arg_list.pop(0)

  # Ensure the next argument exists and is valid
  if len(arg_list) < 1:
    teachUsage()
    sys.exit(0)

  wait_time_secs = int(arg_list.pop(0))
  # My hard-coded list of acceptable values.  How to do for non-trivial input?
  if ((10 == wait_time_secs) or (20 == wait_time_secs)) is not True:
    print "invalid parameter"
    teachUsage()
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
  validateUsage(list(sys.argv))
  time.sleep(wait_time_secs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: You can make a list of acceptable values. `good_wait_times = [10, 20]` and then `if wait_time_secs not in good_wait_times:` I don't think that's O(1), though; I know Python has some data structures with O(1) access. A dictionary, perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to include all the acceptable values like this:

```
acceptable_values = set([10, 20])
```

and then change your condition to:

```
if wait_time_secs not in acceptable_values:
    teachUsage()
```

A set will ensure O(1) lookup.